# failed httpd starting on a centos/apache web server

Tags: apache, webserver, httpd

I installed a ffmpeg module on  a web server (centos)

after that httpd broke.

How can I fixed it?

when I typed:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd start
```

I got this error:

```
Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 5 of /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-directories.conf: Invalid command 'Order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration [FAILED]
```

And the content of httpd-directories.conf is:

```
<Directory />
    Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride None

    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>

<Directory /home>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Indexes Limit Options=Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,ExecCGI,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch,None
    Options IncludesNoExec Includes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch ExecCGI

    <Limit GET POST OPTIONS PROPFIND>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Limit>
    <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS PROPFIND>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </LimitExcept>
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Indexes Limit Options=Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,ExecCGI,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch,None

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_Engine On
        suPHP_UserGroup webapps webapps
        SetEnv PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/cgi-bin>
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Do you also upgrade Apache to 2.4? Googling with query `Invalid command 'Order'` will take you to [common problem when upgrading apache 2.2 -> 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#commonproblems)

Comment: No I don't upgrate Apache,I just installed ffmpeg module

Comment: Please post the apache version (by running `apachectl -v`) and all module loaded by apache (by running `apachectl -M`)

Comment: Your configuration is invalid. `<Directory />` should not have just `/`, but should contain full path to your web root.

Comment: @edvinas.me - the configuration is valid, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory

Answer (score 1):

Replace these lines:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
```

With:

```
Require all denied
```

Also make sure both of these modules are loaded:

```
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
```

Source: http://systembash.com/content/apache-2-4-upgrade-and-the-invalid-command-order-error/